# Validating required input before onlick submit redirect

Tags: html, forms, input, onclick

I am writing the following HTML code which requires certain input values and has a submit button which redirects to a different site when clicked. Currently the Submit button redirects even if no value is entered into the input boxes. I want the submit button to only work if all the input values are filled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Please enter the following information</h3>

<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" required><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" required><br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" required><br>
  <label for="UserID">UserID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="UserID" name="UserID" value="" required><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" required><br><br>
  <input onclick="window.location.href = 'https://example.site';" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your submit isn't properly structured.

You see, if you replace your input submit with a button, it works perfectly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Please enter the following information</h3>

<form action="https://example.site">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" required><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" required><br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" required><br>
  <label for="UserID">UserID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="UserID" name="UserID" value="" required><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" required><br><br>
  <button>Submit</button>
  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

All you would have to change is add the link which you want it to redirect to in the `action` defined in the `form`.

This is the recommended method.

Keep in mind that you should always perform server-side checks regardless of whether there is a `required` attribute in the input field, as it can easily be removed.